# How to fix an error in which my FOR EACH ROW statement does not move to the next row

Tags: mysql

```
USE myDatabase;
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `myDatabase`.`master_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `master` FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO Encryption (master_AccountID, master_AccountName, TeamOps_DL, AccountKeys, KeyARNs) 
SELECT AccountID, AccountName, TeamOps_DL, AccountKeys, KeyARNs 
FROM master;
```

The problem I am running into is that when I copy a set of inserts into the master account, only the first record correctly inserts (first into master and then into encryption). It then throws an error for the rest of the inserts

> (ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '*********-[accountName]' for key 'PRIMARY'.

So it seems to be starting over at the top of the list again and getting stuck there. I'm not sure why it's not moving to the next row. Any insights are appreciated!

Comment: i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query).. You should also provide the insert query you are using..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that there is no `WHERE` condition on your `INSERT ... SELECT`, so the first row that the trigger operates on inserts **all** the data from `master` into `Encryption`. The insert of the second row then attempts to do the same thing, resulting in the duplicate entry error you are seeing. You probably want something like this instead which will only insert the data associated with the new `AccountId`:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `myDatabase`.`master_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `master` FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO Encryption (master_AccountID, master_AccountName, TeamOps_DL, AccountKeys, KeyARNs) 
SELECT AccountID, AccountName, TeamOps_DL, AccountKeys, KeyARNs 
FROM master
WHERE AccountId = NEW.AccountID;
```

Comment: i doubt this will completely solve it.. i have a feeling the topicstarter might need to replace `INSERT` for `REPLACE ` in this answer... But hard to know for sure without table structure , example data and the used insert query...

Comment: @RaymondNijland Agreed, it's hard to be sure, but I think this is a valid interpretation of the question. If I'm proven wrong there's always the `delete` button!

Comment: "but I think this is a valid interpretation of the question. If I'm proven wrong there's always the delete button!" if it does not work ive might given a suggestion which might work

Comment: The where condition was the issue - forgot about that! Thank you! It's working fine now...

Comment: @RaymondNijland no need for the `delete` button! :-)